# hanged or hung?

Tags: past-tense

Source: [Parents receive body of first Russian to die in Syria, doubt suicide](http://news.yahoo.com/parents-russian-soldier-serving-syria-son-died-120323415.html)

Example:

> The body of the first Russian serviceman confirmed dead in four weeks of air strikes in Syria was delivered on Tuesday to his parents, who said they were not convinced by the military's account that their 19-year-old son had **hanged** himself.

I don't understand it. What really is the past participle of *hang*? I've always thought that it was *hung*. Well, after all, we do say:

> Don't get **hung** up on the problem too much. Everything will be fine in the end.

Comment: The verb 'hang' has two participles - hung & hanged. [Use hanged to referring someone's *execution*. Or else it's hung](http://grammar.about.com/od/alightersideofwriting/a/hangedgloss.htm).

Comment: We should also note that ["hung" has a slang meaning](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Hung) which "hanged" does not.  Mostly this does not matter much, but it's part of why you should avoid saying "he was hung".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [The Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/hanged-hung/):

> **Hung** is the past tense and past participle of **hang** in most of that
>   verb’s senses. For instance, yesterday you might have **hung** a picture
>   on the wall, **hung** a right turn, and **hung** your head in sorrow. The
>   exception comes where **hang** means to put to *death by hanging*. The past
>   tense and past participle of **hang** in this sense, and only in this
>   sense, is **hanged**.
>
> When someone is **hung** out of malice but with no intent to kill, as
>   described in the example below, **hung** is the conventional word:
>
> ```
> They hung him by chains and tortured him. [Day Press News]
> ```

Comment: +1. A remark in case OP is confused: a lot of native speakers get this "wrong" and use "hung" even in the context of an execution, so don't be surprised if you've heard it both ways.

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hang

Comment: According to the link, the use of hung in the sense under discussion isn't at all wrong. The thing is that hung is seldom used, whereas the usual and common use in modern English is hanged.

Answer (score 1):

According to Merriam-Webster's usage note ["Is it 'Hung' or 'Hanged'?"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/hung-or-hanged) eithr may be used and is correct:

> A stripped-down version of why we have these two different words is that the word hang came from two different verbs in Old English (and possibly also one from Old Norse). One of these Old English verbs was what we might think of as a regular verb, and this gave rise to hanged; the other was irregular, and ended up becoming hung.
>
> Hanged and hung were used interchangeably for hundreds of years, although over time the one from the irregular verb (hung) eventually became the more common one. Hanged retained its position when used to refer to death by hanging, possibly due to being favored by judges who were passing a sentence. However, both forms are commonly found, and both are commonly found used in either sense.
>
> Is the distinction important? It's still commonly found in usage guides, which typically say that the past and the past participle of hang should be hanged only when referring to a person being subjected to death. Hung is preferred, at least by people who make a distinction, in almost every circumstance. However, not everyone makes this distinction. The Merriam-Webster Dictionary of English Usage has a take on this that differs slightly from the one commonly found in usage guides:
>
> > The distinction between hanged and hung is not an especially useful one (although a few commentators claim otherwise). It is, however, a simple one and certainly easy to remember. Therein lies its popularity. If you make a point of observing the distinction in your writing, you will not thereby become a better writer, but you will spare yourself the annoyance of being corrected for having done something that is not wrong.